# Sharing WMS/WMTS parameters list

Tags: qgis

I configured my Qgis Desktop with some configuration of Webmap Server (WMS and WMTS).

I can see them in

```
Option > advanced > Qgis folder
```

How it is possible to get and share all of theses parameters for different desktop ? are there in sqlite.db or a config file in my locals ? I didn't find them.

My wish is to make different configuration from my desktop and share them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the "Add Wms Layer" dialog there is a **Save** button that allows to export some or all connexions as XML file.

[image]

Similarly, using the **Load** Button, you can import these XML files